# The type or namespace name 'SpecialEffects' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following this Unity [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-an-Android-App-Using-Unity/) which includes this code snippet to include in a script:

```
 private static SpecialEffects instance;
```

But when compiling, Unity throws the error:

> The type or namespace name 'SpecialEffects' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It seems like the `SpecialEffects` namespace is outdated, I'm using Unity version `2019.3.3f1`. Is there an updated definition to use, or is there another issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make Singleton from your current script.
"SpecialEffects" should be the name of your script

Comment: The script name is `SpecialEffects.cs`, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: public class SpecialEffects : MonoBehaviour { // your code} after all using if it is not done